# A confusion about linear span of modified de Bruijn sequence

Tags: stream-cipher

Recently i'm reading ["Cryptographically Strong de Bruijn Sequences
with Large Periods"](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2012/cacr2012-20.pdf) . In the section 2 `2.1 Basic Definitions and Properties` , property 1 says that $$2n<LS_s\leq2^n-2$$ for a span $n$ sequence. The author claims that this bound comes from "[Characterizations of Generators for Modified de Bruijn Sequences](http://ac.els-cdn.com/019688589290021N/1-s2.0-019688589290021N-main.pdf?_tid=072d8524-4174-11e3-a5aa-00000aacb361&acdnat=1383145414_6721b382c0556da645caee634dfe23d3)". I go through it, but i never find  this bound in it.

I wonder how this bound comes?  Can someone prove it? Or does someone know some related paper about it?  thanks ..